# Organize Array Items

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript array:

```
var allItems = ['BBL_NO1', 'BBL_NO2', 'BBL_N03',  'BBL_NO4', 'AAL_NO1', 'AAL_NO2', 'MML_NO1', 'MML_NO2'];
```

Now I want to sort the array in this format, to put the values in a dropdown:

```
var sorted = { 'BBL': ['BBL_NO1', 'BBL_NO2', 'BBL_N03',  'BBL_NO4'],
               'AAL': ['AAL_NO1', 'AAL_NO2'],
               'MML': ['MML_NO1', 'MML_NO2']};
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: You should avoid asking yes/no questions, otherwise Scott will show up.  :D  It's better to ask open-ended questions, "how can i do ____"

Comment: Really, you should avoid asking yes/no questions, otherwise people won't know what it is you are actually asking. Sure, anything is possible, but what have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: How would you solve this as a human?  If you had that list on paper, how would you make the transformation?  If you can do it, it's reasonable a computer can do it, and using the same algorithm.

Comment: Ok @ScottMarcus I have now changed my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

**Example:**

```js
var allItems = ['BBL_NO1', 'BBL_NO2', 'BBL_N03',  'BBL_NO4', 'AAL_NO1', 'AAL_NO2', 'MML_NO1', 'MML_NO2'];

var sorted = allItems.reduce(function (acc, item) {
      var mainPart = item.split('_')[0];
      if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(mainPart)) {
          acc[mainPart] = [];     
      }
      acc[mainPart].push(item);
      return acc;
      
    
}, {});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz why ?

Comment: @NinaScholz you asked how to get the values in a particular format *for the purposes of using in a dropdown*.  You did not ask how to put the values in a dropdown.

Comment: `Now I want to sort the array in this format, to put the values in a dropdown:` The OP wants the array in that format so he can put the values in a dropdown. It is not part of the question

Comment: maybe you spend a variable for the splitted part.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas you are right, I just need help with sorting the list. I know how to put it in a dropdown (and perhaps that was of topic in my question).
I will try your code.

Comment: @chichi `acc` is the main object that contains all the data. `item` represent every single item in the array. `reduce` function make a loop inside it.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas When I run your code I get output [object Object]. How can I get it to work?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas I now get it to work, but I get the output {AAL: Array[2], BBL: Array[4], MML: Array[2]}. I really need the output above. Or else, how can I access the Array starting with for example ALL?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Never mind my previous comments, I got it to work thanks to you! You made my day, thank you so much! Your solution is brilliant.

Comment: @chichi You're welcome. i'm so happy to hear that ^_^ .